# rtMedia api and json request

Tags: json, request

i have installed rtMedia on my web-site(which i have already installed buddypress) and now i’m trying to write an android application using the api of rtMedia but when i try to do a request like `http://example.com/rtmedia_api/wp_login/?username=USER&password=PASS` it display me “NOT FOUND”. 
I have also tryed using the endpoint, like this `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/rtmedia_api/wp_login/?username=USER&password=PASS` in this case it display me “0″.
I don’t understand how to use this api with json code to do json request.
I use also other plugin which have api and to perform a request i just need to type something like this `http://example.com/api/?json=get_recent_posts/?cookie=COOKIE`
Why it dosen’t work whith rtMedia api??
(sorry for my bad english :D )

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way rtMedia API will work.
Please check this [doc](https://rtcamp.com/rtmedia/docs/developer/json-api/) about rtMedia JSON API.

For any queries regarding rtMedia, you can create a support request [here](https://rtcamp.com/support/forum/rtmedia/)

Comment: I have found a simalar question on rtCamp support forum.
Thank for your reply!!

Answer (score 0):

The rtmedia api plugin requires you to submit it via **POST** request (even though the confusing 'documentation' tells you otherwise with some functions). The easiest way to go about this is to create a form using the `method="POST"` and `action="yourhost.domain/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"`. Another way to go about this is by using javascript (which I presume you will be using) and creating a formdata object like so: `var formData_rtmedia = new FormData();` and appending (for example wp_login) the strings of your input field like this:

```
// _(id) is a function that returns document.getElementById(id)

var data1 = _('wp_login_input1').value;
var data2 = _('wp_login_input2').value;

if(data1 != undefined && data1 != '') {formData_rtmedia.append('username', data1);}
if(data1 != undefined && data1 != '') {formData_rtmedia.append('password', data2);}
```

Using the if dataX not equals undefined and not equals empty string check ensures the fields that are optional can be empty and won't populate the postdata object with empty or null values. The object can be sent using ajax (aka an XMLHttpRequest object) like this:

```
var xhr;

function ajax(method, url, async, formData) {

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else                      {xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');}

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.status != 200) {/* handle error */}
            else                  {/* handle response */}        
        } else {
            // display ajax loader or do something fancy
        }
    }

    xhr.open(method, url, async);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

and calling it in your rtmedia javascript file like so: `ajax('POST', url, true, formData_rtmedia);`